# Store data into a SQL Server table through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to save data to SQL Server, my code as follows:

```py
def engine_():
   db_user = ''
   db_password = ''
   db_host = ''
   db_name = ''
   connection_format = 'mssql+pymssql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}?charset=utf8'
   connection_str = connection_format.format(db_user, db_password, db_host, db_name)
   engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_str)
   return engine

engine = engine_()
df.to_sql('111', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

But it dies with following error:

[image]

Then I try to modify charset=GBK, it dies again：

[image]

I found the problem is column 'title' can not encoded properly, I tried to use normalize method, but it doesn't work:

```py
df['title'] = df['title'].str.normalize('NFKD')
df.to_sql('111', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem, and why raise an error message 20002 when using charset=utf8?

Part of 'title' data listing here:

| title |
| --- |
| Artificial Plant Simulation Flower Lotus Water Lily Cumpleaños Para Niña |
| 10cm artificial floating water lily EVA lotus pond ornaments artificial lotus pond aquarium plant ornaments |
| Gauge White Floral Stem Wire Iron Wire Artificial Flower Arrangement Wrapping Strip For Wedding Party DIY Flower Craft |

Comment: Perhaps you're not encoding the data correctly. When using UTF-8 encoding the `ñ` character (U+00F1) should be encoded as the byte sequence `0xC3 0xB1`.

Comment: Please note your first posted code block cannot work since method does not include a `return` statement which may be reason for first error since `engine = None` -entirely irrespective of unicode data.

Comment: I forgot to include return statement in the question，thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It is include return statement in my original code, but it raise an error with error message 20002 when using charset=utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizing a Series of strings converts entire Series to a unicode normal form in case the column contains varying forms across rows. This action does not necessarily convert all data to UTF-8.

Consider extending your call by explicitly calling `Series.str.encode` to convert to UTF-8 bytes which may migrate data to database on a UTF-8 charset connection:

```py
df['title'] = df['title'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('utf-8')
```